# Portal 2 physics - one moving portal

Tags: energy-conservation, momentum, velocity, relative-motion, quantum-teleportation

A problem is posted and solved so many times on 9gag - till yet no good answer.

The problem: you have two portals (one moving and one still standing). The one moving reach a still standing cube: what will happen? The cube will a) fall out of the second portal or b) fly with the velocity of portal A out of portal B?

Here is one answer by an "engineer":

[image: Portal 2]

I don't trust the answer, because it's circular argumentation. He assumes that `V_A=V_B`, he tells us what `V_{A,B}` are and reduce the new equation to `V_A=V_B` So he ends at the start, where he claimed again, saying he solved it mathematically.

**How I see the problem**

I think of a the portal as a hula hoop. I throw the hula hoop ring over a cube. There will not be a momentum transfer, the cube will not move relatively to the whole system, but when you are the hula hoop, the cube will relatively comes to you.

Translated to portals, there will still not be an energy transfer - portal A will not be slown down by passing the cube. So if B should happen a) we would create energy, b) portal B is moving away from the cube, and by this process both portals will slow down or answer (A) is correct.

**At the end I just think: this is pure imagination and this will never ever exist in real life.**

Comment: "*The problem: you have two portals...*" the problem ends here. You don't have two portals. Nobody does.

Comment: Since we're already talking about fictional physics, the right answer is just 'whatever the game's physics engine does'. Depending on how you code it, either answer is right.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform so the answer is: this will never ever exist?

Comment: Well not that it will never exist, this you cannot prove. The answer is: depending on how you define the portals as physical entities. Because you don't have them now, we can't predict how they behave. You're question can be restated as: if you cross a portal, do you have in the other side the same speed as before (relative to the portal) or speed zero? You decide. First case answer is B, second case, answer is A.

Comment: From the perspective of the portal, the cube is moving towards it; and in that frame of reference, the cube will continue with the same momentum when it comes out of the other portal. But yeah, "we deal with mainstream physics here"...

Comment: @Floris but I don't see where the energy comes from?

Comment: @AlexC.Johnson you worry about conservation of energy in a **portal**? The Aperture Science motto is "We do what we must, because we can" - not "we obey the laws of physics"...

Comment: I think it would be better if you take out 'portals' and replace it with 'assume portals are two ends of a wormhole'. That might help in others being more willing to answer your problem.

Comment: @Floris portals do not break the laws of physics. And there's a well established theoretical model of it which I'm sure you heard of it before... Whether or not they exist or if we can create them is still unknown. But there is no law of physics that we know of that prevents their exitance. I'm taking about wormholes of course